# Mosquito problem

Tags: bedroom, insects

How do you keep mosquitoes out of the bedroom? Am allergic to insecticide spray.

I have tried getting net on the windows. But the problem is when I open my door, they easily get in.

Comment: You can hang a mosquito net over the bed, but they can still get in at the same time as you do. You could also try organic repellents such as aromatic oils if you don't like chemical ones.

Comment: In areas where they're *really* fierce, such as Alaska, a mud-room (i.e., a short entrance-way  with inner and outer doors, serving as an "air lock") can help. Even just Permethrin-treated overlapping nets at the inside end of the hall can be effective.

Answer (score 2):

A small fan does well ; blowing toward the bed. Mosquitos can not fly well in moving air. A ceiling fan will also work for most of the room, but is more costly.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop flying insects from entering a doorway with an "air curtain" device, which blows air down across the doorway and hinders flying insects from passing through the doorway. (Check Google and Amazon for photos and description.)

Answer (score 0):

- **Never open your windows in the evening with the lights on inside.** If you want to ventilate, make sure all the lights are out OR you have mosquito netting over every open window.
- As above, so below: if you're sitting outside in the evening, turn off the lights to make it harder for mosquitoes to find you.
- Install a drawable / foldable / unrollable mosquito net over your door.
- If you have curtains, open the window then pass the curtains over and close them across the open window as a makeshift net. (I have combo curtains - one set translucent and light, the other opaque and heavy - so I use the light curtains as my "net".) You'll get less of a breeze, but also fewer mosquitoes.
- If you have a patio, garden, balcony: **get rid of any shallow standing water** you don't need. Common sources of standing water include potted plant dishes and bird baths; **empty and refresh these every 5-6 days.** [Mosquitoes need 7-10 days to breed in shallow standing water (under 60cm/2ft)](https://www3.epa.gov/npdes/pubs/sw_wnv.pdf). Look for abandoned cups, plastic bags... clean up anything that might hold even a small amount of water.
- You said you're allergic to insecticide spray, but didn't specify if you're allergic to repellents (the kind you spray or spread directly on your skin). **Citronella-based repellents** are less aggressive than heavy-duty outdoor repellents like DEET, and might not cause the same reaction. (They're also less effective and less long-lasting, so I wouldn't rely on them in malarial areas, but they *do* work. Look for ones aimed at children or babies if you have sensitive skin.)
- I've never found citronella candles, sticks, oils etc to do anything. Unless you like the smell - which honestly is really nice - don't waste your money.
- If you're in the US and want to spend money, here's an article from the NYT recommending several airborne repellents: https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter/blog/citronella-candles-mosquito-repellents-dont-work/ But I'd put my emphasis on passive methods first.

A caveat: I live in the Mediterranean part of Europe, where mosquitoes are a concern but not as bad as the more tropical parts of the world; summers in my town in particular are comparatively cool and dry (30ºC/86ºF day, 13ºC/55ºF night, +10ºC in heatwaves), so mosquitoes are relatively easy to ward off. Depending on how severe the mosquito problem is in your area, you may need to take more serious measures.

Answer (score 0):

Mosquitos tend to start getting active when the sun starts to go down.

In addition to keeping your windows and doors closed and remaining in doors from just prior to the sun going down I would advise doing two things. Firstly get a [mosquito net for the bed](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=mosquito%20nets%20for%20beds&iax=images&ia=images) and use it correctly.

The second thing is to initially make your bedroom and then your home  hostile to mosquitos by having [mosquito repellent plants](https://www.proflowers.com/blog/plants-that-repel-mosquitoes) ([and these](https://www.thespruce.com/plants-that-repel-mosquitoes-4583885)) near windows, doorways and eventually in your garden.

Have some of the plants near the bed and elsewhere in the bedroom.

I can't suggest any plant in particular in case you are sensitive to some of them. All I can suggest is to trial some and see what works for you.